# Select product from mysql where array $key = id

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, session

I have a session containing an array with key and value assigned to each array. After the array is set and stored in the session, I would like to fetch and echo out all information from mysql table where the $key of the array is = to the id in my table.

I am using a foreach loop to echo each $key and $value of each array already, but i want to echo the data from the mysql table which equals each key as well.

**My table**

```
id         |       name       |      animalheight     |
-------------------------------------------------------
2012dog                dog                    1m            
2022cat                cat                    0.3m
```

So I would like to echo the name and animalheight, if the session key is set and equals to the id of the table.

**The part of the code that gives an error**

```
///////////////DUMPING EVERYTHING FROM DATABASE////////////////////////////////////


$sql = "select * from products where $key =$id"; 
$myData =  mysql_query($sql,$con);

if($record = mysql_fetch_array($myData))
{
    echo "<br/>";
    echo "||||||||||||||||". $row['name']. "||||||||||||||||";
    echo "<br/>";
}
/////////////////////DUMPING EVERYTHING FROM DATABASE/////////////////////////////////////
```

**My Full Code**

```
//code
<?php
//////////////////////////////////////////////
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","****","");
mysql_select_db("*********",$con);
//////////////////////////////////////////////
 session_start();

// create an array
$my_array=array( '2012dog' => 1 , '2022cat' => 2);


// put the array in a session variable
if(!isset($_SESSION['animals']))
    $_SESSION['animals']=$my_array;

 // move submit code outside of foreach loop
 if (isset($_POST["submit"])) 
{
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['aaa']); $i++) {
    $aaa = $_POST['aaa'][$i];
    $key_var = $_POST['ke'][$i];

    // setting the session spesific session array value different for each     key  
    $_SESSION['animals'][$key_var] = $aaa;
}
}
?>



<form method="post" action="">
<?php
// loop through the session array with foreach
foreach($_SESSION['animals'] as $key=>$value)
{   

////////////////////////////DUMPING EVERYTHING FROM     DATABASE////////////////////////////////////////////////


$sql = "select * from products where $key =$id"; 
$myData =  mysql_query($sql,$con);

if($record = mysql_fetch_array($myData))
{
    echo "<br/>";
    echo "||||||||||||||||". $row['name']. "||||||||||||||||";
    echo "<br/>";
}
////////////////////////////DUMPING EVERYTHING FROM     DATABASE////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // and print out the values

    echo "Product ID is " .$key. " Quantity is ";

    // getting the updated value from input box
    ?>
        <input type="text" name="aaa[]" value="<?php echo $value ; ?>"     size="2" />
        <!-- take a hidden input with value of key -->
        <input type="hidden" name="ke[]" value="<?php echo $key; ?>"><br>

    <?php
}
?>

<input type="submit" value="Update value of key" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

THANKS IN ADVANCE!

Comment: I tired to do $key='key';..... and then saying select where key = $id but it didnt work ;s

Comment: Undefined variable: id             and also       mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

Comment: 6 dozen wrong things here, but `id ='$key'` key is a string so it needs quotes, the loop is a bad idea, mysql_* is a bad idea

Comment: everything works but the ///////////DUMPING EVERYTHING FROM DATABASE/////////// part

Comment: what else can I do instead of the loop then :S. Because i need to fetch the info based on the array key :(

Comment: concatenate and so one query

Comment: Where is the value `$id` supposed to come from? Per your error, it is an undefined variable - it has not been populated at the time you attempt to use it in that SQL string.

Comment: do you need the session? just loop `$my_array`

Comment: I' am confused because there are two loops, and the $key value of the array is even more confusing because I am not sure how to say find all values where the $key = to the id in the mysql table

Comment: your confused? you wrote that abomination.

Comment: i know lol. I need to take out the fetch from database part. Everything else works perfectly. Its just the fetch ...

Comment: how else can I gather the rest of the information from the database based on the session keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like this,

```
// First get all the keys
$key_array = array_keys($_SESSION['animals']);

// Get all records
$sql = "select * from products"; 
$myData =  mysql_query($sql,$con);

// Loop through each record and see if $row['id'] is present in the $key_array or not 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($myData)){
    if(in_array($row['id'], $key_array)){
        // display records 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Rajdeep Paul, but the problem of the undefined variable still stands.  $sql = "select * from products where '$key' =$id";

Comment: You can do just `$sql = select * from products` and then loop through each record to see if `$row['id']` is present in the `$key_array` or not. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: is that using the same code above?

Comment: Alirght :) one second let me try

Comment: Almost ;s. I get undefined variable row id
  if(in_array($row['id'], $key_array))

Comment: Try to debug the code. See the contents of array, like this `print_r($key_array)`, echo your id, `echo $row['id']`. Make sure everything is okay.

Comment: when i echo $row['id'], i get Undefined variable: row

Comment: is it working on ur end?

Comment: oops, I mistakenly used `$record` instead of `$row` to fetch each record from the table. I've updated the above code snippet. Please re-try. The same mistake is there in your code also, please rectify that.

Comment: Rajdeep Paul - Thank you, it works. but it only works outside the $key => value loop.

Comment: if its inside, it loops through it. But it works thank you!

Comment: Happy to hear. Please show your gratitude by accepting the answer. :)